# Clojurescript: How to conditionally update a hash map?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to get my head around some CLJS and Reagent, and I'm running into an issue when I try to apply one update or another to an atom.

I have an increment function, `incDieCount`, which increments the value for a particular key in the map.  I've tried to write a function which should decrement the value for a key as well. It works if the value is 0 (it won't decrement below that), but instead of decrementing the current value by one, it *always* sets the value to zero.  What am I missing?

```
(defonce app-state
  (reagent/atom
   {:dice
    {:d4 0
     :d6 0
     :d8 0
     :d10 0
     :d12 0
     :d20 0
     :d100 0}}))

(defn incDieCount [die]
  #(swap! app-state update-in [:dice die] inc))

(defn decDieCount [die]
  (let [count (get-in app-state [:dice die])]
    (if (> 0 count)
      #(swap! app-state update-in [:dice die] dec)
      #(swap! app-state assoc-in [:dice die] 0))))


(defn diceEl [[die count]]
  ^{:key die} [:li
               (str (name die) ": " count)
               [:button {:on-click (incDieCount die)}
                "Add"]
               [:button {:on-click (decDieCount die)}
                "Subtract"]])

(defn page [ratom]
  [:ul
    (for [tuple (:dice @ratom)] (diceEl tuple))])


(defn reload []
  (reagent/render [page app-state]
                  (.getElementById js/document "app")))

(defn ^:export main []
  (dev-setup)
  (reload))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add to @Ming's answer: first, you need `(> count 0)` instead of `(> 0 count)` - the latter translates to `count < 0`.

Second, it's not recommended to work with atoms non-atomically - in your `decDieCount` code, the condition `count > 0` is checked when the component is rendered, not when the button is clicked (what if the value of the dice changes in-between?)

It would be better to rewrite `decDieCount` as follows:

```
(defn decDieCount [die]
  (fn []
    (swap! app-state update-in [:dice die]
           #(if (pos? %) (dec %) 0))))
```

This way you are guaranteed that the new value of the die is based on its current value.

Comment: That did it, thanks! One question; why do I need the anonymous function?

Comment: We have two anonymous functions here - one is to make a closure around the `die` key (and you have a similar anonymous function in your `incDieCount` code), and the second one transforms the value of the atom within `swap!` - since your transform is more complex than a simple `inc` or `dec` (it involves checking the count first), you need to express it in a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

To get an atom's current value, you need to dereference it: `@app-state`.

```
(let [count (get-in @app-state [:dice die])] ...)
```